# Can Masonry items be aligned to all 4 container edges?

Tags: jquery, alignment, masonry

Not sure if it's possible but I'd like all items to align with the container edges. For example, I have a number of different-sized items like this:

[image]

and I'd like the result to look something like this:

[image]

I think it's probably not possible with Masonry, but is it possible at all? Is there an algorithm to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible with masonry like alignment where the items are aligned vertically, but you can certainly create a grid that looks fairly similar to masonry but also align to all 4 edges of its container. See this: http://www.techbits.de/2011/10/25/building-a-google-plus-inspired-image-gallery/